# Problemas validando campos de formulario de contacto

Tags: javascript, html, comparaciones

Tengo una página para que me contacten y necesito que todos los campos sean rellenados. Tengo que utilizar `alert` para avisar que no ha introducido algún campo y cuál es ese campo. Intenté utilizar `isNaN` pero no me funcionó.

Tambien intente esto pero no funcionó del todo bien:

```js
function validar(name, email, msg)
{
    if (name="")
    {
        alert(No has introducido tu nombre)
    }
    else if (email="")
    {
        alert("No has introducido tu email")
    }
    else if (msg="")
    {
        alert("no has introducido ningún mensaje")
    }
    else
    {
        alert("El mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente")
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo y donde llamas a esa función? ¿Qué valores le envías? , podría añadir el código completo ,intente  [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en Español @Luca, no queda demasiado clara tu pregunta, por favor editala y agregale más información para poder ayudarte. Aquí un [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que te ayudará a formular una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Estás iniciando con JavaScript, revisa este enlace: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Las comparaciones se realizan utilizando doble signo y triple signo igual como puedes ver en enlace

```
 function validar(name, email, msg)
      {
        if (name==="")
        {
          alert(No has introducido tu nombre)
        }
        else if (email==="")
        {
          alert("No has introducido tu email")
        }
        else if (msg==="")
        {
          alert("no has introducido ningún mensaje")
        }
        else
        {
          alert("El mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente")
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

En JavaScript un signo de igual se utiliza para asignar un valor a una variable. Es por ello que el código que pones en la pregunta no funciona, es decir, estas asignando valores a una variable en lugar de realizar comparaciones.

En cuanto a la forma de hacer comparaciones en JavaScript, existen dos tipos, la comparación abstracta y la comparación estricta.

En una comparación abstracta, los operandos de la izquierda y de la derecha podrían ser convertidos siguiendo un algoritmo propio de JavaScript. Algunos recomiendan evitar el uso de esta comparación porque se presta a confusión

En una comparación estricta, los operandos de la izquierda y de la derecha **no** son convertidos.

- Para la comparación abstracta se usa `==`.
- Para la comparación estricta se usa `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que cada campo sea requerido solo tienes que añadir el atributo `required` en el campo que desees. Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" required>
```

Pero si lo que quieres es validar por ti mismo los campos entonces el código sería mas o menos así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var nombre = $('#nombre');
var correo = $('#correo');
var msg = $('#msg');

$('#aceptar').click(function (event) {
    if(nombre.val() === ""){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('el nombre es requerido');
        console.log(nombre);
    }else if(correo.val() === ""){
        alert('el correo es requerido');
        event.preventDefault();
    }else if(msg.val() === ""){
        alert('el mensaje es requerido');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <label>
        Nombre:
        <input type="text" id="nombre" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        Correo:
        <input type="email" id="correo">
    </label>
    <label>
        Mensaje:
        <input type="text" id="msg">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" id="aceptar">
</form>
```

Ojo: aquí utilizo la librería de [JQuery](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Para más información sobre esta librería ve a la [página oficial](https://jquery.com/)